# stop loading image on form submit if required field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

On https://bm-translations.de/#kontakt I've got a form with a submit button, that is replaced with a loading gif, when clicked.

The problem is: if one of the required fields isnt set, the form does not submit but the loading gif appears and doesnt disappear. How to say only appear if all required fields are set?

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="formsubmitbutton">
<input type="submit" name="submitter" value="Submit Button" onclick="ButtonClicked()">
</div>
<div id="buttonreplacement" style="margin-left:30px; display:none;">
<img src="./bilder/preload.gif" alt="loading...">
</div>
```

This is the JS:

```
function ButtonClicked()
{
   document.getElementById("formsubmitbutton").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
   document.getElementById("buttonreplacement").style.display = ""; // to display
   return true;
}
var FirstLoading = true;
function RestoreSubmitButton()
{
   if( FirstLoading )
   {
      FirstLoading = false;
      return;
   }
   document.getElementById("formsubmitbutton").style.display = ""; // to display
   document.getElementById("buttonreplacement").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
}
// To disable restoring submit button, disable or delete next line.
document.onfocus = RestoreSubmitButton;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/z7wfj880/2/

```js
ButtonClicked = function(){
   var validate = true;
   $('input:required').each(function(){
      if($(this).val().trim() === ''){
         validate = false;
      }
   });
   if(validate) { 
      document.getElementById("formsubmitbutton").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
      document.getElementById("buttonreplacement").style.display = ""; // to display
      return true;
   }
}
var FirstLoading = true;
function RestoreSubmitButton()
{
   if( FirstLoading )
   {
      FirstLoading = false;
      return;
   }
   document.getElementById("formsubmitbutton").style.display = ""; // to display
   document.getElementById("buttonreplacement").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
}
// To disable restoring submit button, disable or delete next line.
document.onfocus = RestoreSubmitButton;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Middle Name"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required/>

<div id="formsubmitbutton">
  <input type="submit" name="submitter" value="Submit Button" onclick="ButtonClicked()">
</div>
<div id="buttonreplacement" style="margin-left:30px; display:none;">
  <img src="./bilder/preload.gif" alt="loading...">
</div>
```

First of all do a `trim` of **required** `input` field, so that if any user provide spaces it will remove the extra spaces in front & end.

`Loop` through all the required `input` & check for empty input.

Comment: Please format your code and use the lowerSnakeCase for functions.

Comment: @DirtyDev... function name provided by OP.

Answer (score 1):

Check for [validation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp) of required fields.

If all fields are set then only call `buttonreplacement`.

For Eg: If you have fields `field1` and `field2`.

```
f1 = document.getElementById("id_field1").value;
f2 = document.getElementById("id_field2").value;

if (f1!=null || f1!=undefined || f1!="" || f2!=null || f2!=undefined || f2!=""){
    document.getElementById("buttonreplacement").style.display = "none";
}
else{
       document.getElementById("buttonreplacement").style.display = "block";
    }
```

You can always improve your code using Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a modular function to display and hide the `loader`.

Now when you click the `submit` button, you can check for your form validation and `toggle` the loader easily. I have hardcoded the `false`, but you can check for the appropriate validation.

```js
function displayLoading(form, loader) {
  document.getElementById("formsubmitbutton").style.display = form; // to undisplay
   document.getElementById("buttonreplacement").style.display = loader; // to display
}

function ButtonClicked()
{
  if(false) { // form in valid 
    displayLoading('none', '');
  } else {
    displayLoading('', 'none');
  }
}
var FirstLoading = true;
function RestoreSubmitButton()
{
   if( FirstLoading )
   {
      FirstLoading = false;
      return;
   }
   document.getElementById("formsubmitbutton").style.display = ""; // to display
   document.getElementById("buttonreplacement").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
}
// To disable restoring submit button, disable or delete next line.
document.onfocus = RestoreSubmitButton;
```

```html
<div id="formsubmitbutton">
<input type="submit" name="submitter" value="Submit Button" onclick="ButtonClicked()">
</div>
<div id="buttonreplacement" style="margin-left:30px; display:none;">
<img src="http://gph.is/1cYmtb9" alt="loading...">
</div>
```